# Bilingual French-English dictionary for the Amazon Kindle

Tags: dictionary, kindle, french

I am looking a bilingual French-English dictionary that I can use on my Amazon Kindle Paperwhite. I try to read the French newspaper *Le Monde* on my Kindle, but there are words that I don't understand. I have a French monolingual dictionary, but I don't always understand the definitions. Furthermore, it doesn't find inflected forms (especially verbs) or contractions.

So I'm looking for a French-English dictionary for the Kindle which:

- can be used conveniently while reading a newspaper;
- has entries for inflected forms.

Comment: That would be tough considering the constraints of the Kindle. What device are you using?

Comment: Merci! J'ai une Kindle Paperwhite.

Comment: Les logiciels sont hors sujet ici, même si ils ont un vague rapport avec la langue française. Le sujet du site [french.se], c'est la langue française. Je migre cette question vers un site où elle est acceptable, à condition de traduire en anglais.

Comment: @Gilles Btw you are welcome to cast your opinion on [Are dictionaries off-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/891/903)

Answer (score 1):

The [Collins French to English Dictionary](http://www.amazon.fr/English-Dictionary-Collins-Digital-Dictionaries-ebook/dp/B0033806F0/ref=pd_cp_kinc_0) looks good. You can set it as the default dictionary, this way you'll be able to see definitions while you're reading something. You can also browse it like a normal dictionary.

Comment: Je vais le essai.  J'espere le chercher est bien pour des plusiers de conjugations.  Merci!

Comment: Je vais l'essayer aussi. J'utilise mon iPad comme Kindle... alors ça devrait intéressante.